# ng-repeat link to open detailed view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, view, hyperlink, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been trying to link my thumb elements to open detailed view.
Currently I have this [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZS19AzfHwKJTS0krekV3?p=preview) and for some reason I am not able to get active links in my ng-repeat.

I am trying to set a link on `href="#/promo/{{item.indexOf(item)}}"` (in my example I only applied it to image.html partial - in preview it is the first thumb - image with monkey.)

```
        <span class="image_container">
          <a href="#/promo/{{item.indexOf(item)}}" title="{{ content.submissionTitle }}"><img ng-src="{{rootDirectory}}{{content.data}}" alt="entry photo"></a>
        </span>

        <span class="description">
          <span class="title"><a href="#/promo/{{item.indexOf(item)}}" title="{{ content.submissionTitle }}">{{ content.submissionTitle }}</a></span>
          <span class="text_field">
            {{ content.submissionText }}
          </span>
        </span>
```

Am I doing something wrong or there is a better way to it.

Please advice me on this one

Comment: item.indexOf(item) both are item??

Comment: <content-item ng-repeat="item in content" content="item"></content-item>

Answer (score 1):

check this one,

```
<a href="#/promo/{{$index}}" title ...
```